# Pythonanwhere Facebook app Canvas URL no longer available

Tags: pythonanywhere

Am trying to follow the PythonAnywhere Facebook app example, but get stuck early on trying to set the Canvas URL per PA's instructions. It appears that FB wants to force me to use Heroku for this; and they now call it a "Hosting URL". Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I still see the option at https://developers.facebook.com/apps

```
--> Create New App
--> Select how your app integrates with Facebook
--> App on Facebook
--> Canvas URL + Secure Canvas URL
```

Is it different for you?  The only other thing I can think of is make sure you don't tick the "hosting from Heroku" box on the first step...